# Is it possible to work with 'for loop grep' commands?

Tags: for-loop, awk, grep

I have lots of files in every year directory

and in each file have long and large sentence like this for exmaple

- List item

`home/2001/2001ab.txt`

```
the AAAS kill every one not but me and you and etc
the A1CF maybe color of full fill zombie
```

`home/2002/2002ab.txt`

```
we maybe know some how what
```

`home/2003/2003ab.txt`

```
Mr, Miss boston, whatever
aaas will will will long long
```

and in home directory, I got `home/reference.txt` (list of word file)

```
A1BG
A1CF
A2M
AAAS
```

I'd like to do count how many word in the file `reference.txt` is in every single year file

this is my code where I run in every year directory
`home/2001/`, `home/2002/`, `home/2003/`

```
# awk
function search () {
    awk -v pattern="$1" '$0 ~ pattern {print}'  *.txt > $1
}

# load custom.txt
for i in $(cat reference.txt)
do 
 search $i 
done

# word count
wc -l * > line-count.txt
```

this is my result

`home/2001/A1BG`

```
$cat A1BG
0
```

`home/2001/A1CF`

```
$cat A1CF
1
```

`home/2001/A2M`

```
$cat A2M
0
```

`home/2001/AAAS`

```
$cat AAAS
1
```

`home/2001/line-count.txt`

```
$cat line-count.txt
2021ab.txt 2
A1BG 
A1CF 1
A2M 0
AAAS 1
```

result `line-count.txt` file have all information what I want
but I have to do this work repeat manually
do `cd directory`
do run my code
and then `cd directory`
I have around 500 directory and file, it is not easy

and second problem is wasty bunch of file
create lots of file and takes too much time

because of this at first I'd likt use `grep` command
but I dont' know how to use list of file instead of single word

that is why I use `awk`

How can i do it more simple

Comment: it also doesn't work as `$0 ~ pattern` would think it found the word `the` if a file contained `atheist` or similar. Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input that covers all your requirements including all of the edge cases like substrings and/or regexp metachars and/or cases like `there's` in a file while trying to match `there` along with the expected output given that input.

Comment: Tangentially, [don't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Your Awk script could easily do something else than `print` the line, especially each search phrase to a different file. Simply browsing the existing [tag:awk] questions on this site should bring you a metric boatload of scripts which do more or less what you are asking.

Comment: as Ed morton said, I add testabl sample

Answer (score 0):

> at first I'd likt use grep command but I dont' know how to use list of
> file instead of single word

You might use `--file=FILE` option for that purpose, selected file should hold one pattern per line.

> How can i do it more simple

You might use `--count` option to avoid need of using `wc -l` for that, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
123
456
789
```

and `file1.txt` content be

```
abc123
def456
```

and `file2.txt` content be

```
ghi789
xyz000
```

and `file3.txt` content be

```
xyz000
xyz000
```

then

```
grep --count --file=file.txt file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

gives output

```
file1.txt:2
file2.txt:1
file3.txt:0
```

Observe that no files are created and file without matches does appear in output. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes `file.txt` does not contain character of special meaning for GNU `grep`, if this does not hold do not use this solution.

*(tested in GNU grep 3.4)*

Comment: The fix is easy, if you don't want to use the input as regular expressions, use `grep -F`; perhaps also investigate the `-x` option.

Comment: thx your advice work very well, but I add sample, that I want to count 
file1.txt : xyz000:1, abc123:0
file2.txt : xyz000: 2, abc123 :1
...